# Сортировка списка списков по первому элементу python

Tags: python, list, сортировка

Есть список списков:

```
[[(4, 0.454453), (5, 0.563333),(1, 0.879905)],
[(5, 0.769977), (1, 0.123533),(4, 0.986533)]]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как отсортировать их так, чтобы каждый список сортировался от меньшего к большему по первому элементу, например:

```
[[(1, 0.879905), (4, 0.454453), (5, 0.563333)],
[(1, 0.123533), (4, 0.986533), (5, 0.769977)]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [[(4, 0.454453), (5, 0.563333),(1, 0.879905)], [(5, 0.769977), (1, 0.123533),(4, 0.986533)]]
```

Либо так:

```
[ sorted(i) for i in lst ]
```

Либо так:

```
list(map(sorted, lst))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!